# coercing nil into a number

Tags: ruby, coercion

What is happening here??

```
irb(main):001:0> a= nil
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> b = nil
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> a
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> a+b
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):4
    from :0
irb(main):005:0> if a.nil? or b.nil?; a,b=0;end;
irb(main):006:0* c = a+b
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
    from (irb):6:in `+'
    from (irb):6
    from :0
irb(main):007:0>
```

How can you safely perform arithmetic by transforming nil to an number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to add `nil`? It's specifically designed to be something that represents the lack of a value (note: `nil` is NOT `0`).

If what you're actually wanting to do is set both values to `0` if either is *currently* `nil`, then what you actually want is this:

```
if a.nil? or b.nil?; a,b=0,0; end
```

Your mistake in the code above was the `a,b=0` portion, which only sets the value of `a` to `0` - it sets `b` to `nil` because the left hand side is looking for two values, and only one is provided on the right (so the others are assumed to be `nil`).

Answer (score 5):

Depending on why there's a nil instead of a number, you could decide that it's good for you to consider nil as 0; in that case, you can do something like:

```
c = (a || 0) + (b || 0)
```

This, of course, only makes sense if you *know* why you have a nil instead of a number...

Comment: I personally prefer `or` over `||`, it's just simpler for a lot of people to read (even though I've done enough programming that I wind up reading `||` as "or" anyways :P).

Comment: @Dav: what about the `@foo ||= ...` syntax? I use it a lot, so why not to always use `||`? Actually I'm just rationalizing: I simply prefer `||` over `or` :)

Comment: `||` also has precedence over `or`, so the two are not always interchangeable.

Comment: That precedence is actually why I like it, Jimmy - in my mind, `||` is better saved for actual logic operations most of the time; keeping `or` for actual "I want the actual second value sometimes" cases.

Answer (score 3):

Your parallel assignment (`a, b = 0`) results in `a=0` and `b=nil`, i.e. it assigns `0` to `a` and `nil` to `b`, because there is only one value on the right hand side.

What you want is:
    if a.nil? or b.nil?; a = b = 0; end
    c = a + b

Obviously the code is still broken, since you overwrite any non-nil values of `a` and `b` with 0 when `a` or `b` is nil.

Comment: <3 direct answers to questions.